# Include TEXT from another file before generating PDF

Tags: pdf, include, text-manipulation

I have a tex file which compiles fine and generates PDF without any problem. I need to include text (contents of a text file) from another .txt file at the end of tex file so that generated PDF would have this text in it.

In other words, How can I call another file (text file) to include its contents in a tex file before generating PDF?

Please advise, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can use `\input{}`. Look for more on it.

Comment: If you want to print `file.txt` verbatim, then put `\usepackage{verbatim}` in the preamble and `\verbatiminput{file.txt}` where you want the contents of `file.txt` to appear.

Answer (score 4):

It is not obvious if you want to merge your text file or reproduce it as it is. Hence there are both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

A beginning.

\input{aaa.txt} % your text file


\textbf{But if you want to reproduce your text as it is:}
{\obeylines\obeyspaces
\texttt{
\input{aaa.txt}
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you the reply. But I have "#" symbols in my text files which causing an error while compiling and the error is "! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode." How can I solve this problem? Please advise!!

Comment: @user41006 Maybe my answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142006/read-strings-from-file-that-contains-the-special-character/142012#142012 would be useful?