# Reading files containing # characters

Tags: symbols, external-files

Using this code, I have no problems reading files unless they contain the character '#' (number sign, pound sign or hash character, whatever you call it)

```
\newread\file
\openin\file="C:/Some Directory/File.txt"
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
    \read\file to\fileline 
    \fileline
\repeat
\closein\file
```

Let's say the file 'File.txt' looks like this one:

```
# This line is a comment
variable=value

# This line is also a comment
variable2=value2
```

When the file contains this character, I get the following error:

> You can't use macro parameter character '#' in vertical mode

My goal is to take the content of this file and add it to my PDF document, along with text and formulas written in LaTeX. Any ideas on how to read files containing such characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are there such characters? Do you want to read the file “verbatim”? If you state your real problem, it's possible that a better solution comes out.

Comment: I have added more info to my post, so hopefuly it will be easier for everyone to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: See also [macros - Read strings from file that contains the special character # - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142006/read-strings-from-file-that-contains-the-special-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the file should be used, there are different ways to load it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
# This line is a comment
variable=value

# This line is also a comment
variable2=value2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newread\caissyfile

\begin{document}

\begingroup\catcode`#=12
\openin\caissyfile=\jobname.txt
\loop\unless\ifeof\caissyfile
    \read\caissyfile to\fileline
    \fileline\endgraf
\repeat
\closein\caissyfile
\endgroup

\VerbatimInput{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]